# Comparison of Fibonacci (Multinacci) Functions in Python3

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.x, fibonacci-sequence, memoization

After coming up with a formula [on this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111106/recursive-fibonacci-algorithm-with-variant/25111299#25111299), defeating recursion limits and finding a few new ways of calculating these numbers (as per [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166227/dynamically-changing-the-recursion-limit-for-a-fibonnacci-program-python)), I decided that it was time to write up the solutions and submit them for a proper review.

For those that are not familiar with Fibonacci and more generally, Multinacci numbers, here are the rules:

1. The numbers correspond to the number of pairs of rabbits at year n
2. Rabbits take 1 year to mature
3. Rabbits reproduce after they mature, to produce 1 (or k in the case of Multinacci) pairs of rabbits
4. There is 1 pair at year 1, and none at year 0

```
from functools import lru_cache

limit = 100

# Classic recursive
def fibnum1(n, k=1):
    """Returns the multinacci number of order k at generation n"""
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        return 1
    # build up the cache as needed to defeat recursion bounds
    global limit
    if n > limit:
        for temp_n in range(limit, n, 100):
            _fibnum(temp_n, k)
        limit = n + 100
    return _fibnum(n, k)

# Recursive with matrix multiplication
def fibnum2(n, k=1):
    """Returns the multinacci number of order k at generation n"""
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        return 1
    return _matrix_fib(n, k)[1]

# Iterative
def fibnum3(n, k=1):
    """Returns the multinacci number of order k at generation n"""
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    fibnums = [0, 1, 1]
    for i in range(3, n+1):
        fibnums.append(fibnums[i-1] + k * fibnums[i-2])
    return fibnums[n]

# Helper for fibnum1, memoized of course
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def _fibnum(n, k=1):
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        return 1
    return _fibnum(n-1, k) + k * _fibnum(n-2, k)

# Helper for fibnum2, memoized of course
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def _matrix_fib(n, k):
    if n == 1:
        return [0, 1]
    else:
        f = _matrix_fib(n // 2, k)
        c = k * f[0] * f[0] + f[1] * f[1]
        d = f[1] * (f[1] + 2 * k * f[0])
        if n % 2 == 0:
            return [c, d]
        else:
            return [d, k * c + d]
```

As you can see, there are three distinct functions here for calculating these numbers: `fibnum1`, `fibnum2`, and `fibnum3`. They are *nearly* functionally identical, as all 3 are super fast (memoization for the win!) and work for relatively big numbers quite well. `fibnum2` will fail eventually (dumb recursion limit...), but it is at too large of a number to be practically reached. I would like a comparative review, along with any other comments on **any** aspect of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks fine to me. Just some small suggestion:

Don't define `limit` as a global. You can make it an attribute of the function itself: `fibnum1.limit`

In the matrix version I would return a tuple instead of a list. Also I would define two variables for `f[0]` and `f[1]` as follows:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def _matrix_fib(n, k):
    if n == 1:
        return (0, 1)
    else:
        f0, f1 = _matrix_fib(n // 2, k)
        c = k * f0 * f0 + f1 * f1
        d = f1 * (f1 + 2 * k * f0)
        if n % 2 == 0:
            return (c, d)
        else:
            return (d, k * c + d)
```

Answer (score 2):

I will focus here only on the iterative version, on fibnum3.

It does not make sense to build up an array (of big numbers
using potentially a huge amount of memory) only to use the 
last element of the array as the value returned.

So first make up your mind what you want: the n-th Fibonacci
number or the initial segment of the Fibonnaci sequence of length n.
These are two very different species and usually have quite
different implementations.

So make two functions and also make it clear in the name of the 
functions what you deliver: "multinacci" or "multinacci_list".

```
def multinacci(n, k=1):
    if (n <= 1): return(n)
    x = 0; y = 1
    for _ in range(0, n):
        x, y = y, y + k*x
    return x

[multinacci(n) for n in range(10)]

def multinacci_list(len, k=1):
    if (len == 0): return []
    x = 0; y = 1
    seq = [0]
    for _ in range(len-1):
        x, y = y, y + k*x
        seq.append(x)
    return seq

multinacci_list(10)
```

Now compare the amount of memory you use in the two 
functions if you increase the arguments from 10 to 10000.